# Increment per group but reset per criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I'm using SQL Server and say I have this sample

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableName
    (acct int, seq int,chk int)
;
    
INSERT INTO TableName
    (acct, seq,chk)
VALUES
    (123,1,1),
    (123,2,1),
    (123,3,1),
    (123,4,0),
    (123,5,1),
    (123,6,1),
    (124,1,0),
    (124,2,1),
    (124,3,1),
    (124,4,0),
    (124,5,1),
    (124,6,1)
;
```

I want to produce a counter per acct based on when chk=1 and then resets when chk is 0. The seq is just order I want it to be in .

Is there a way to just do it in the select? If not then a loop is fine just looking a different methods like `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` but I can't get it to how I want.

This is how I want it(Counter being the column I want to create):

```
acct seq chk counter  
123  1   1   1  
123  2   1   2  
123  3   1   3  
123  4   0   0  
123  5   1   1  
123  6   1   2  
124  1   0   0  
124  2   1   1  
124  3   1   2  
124  4   0   0  
124  5   1   1  
124  6   1   2
```

I tried this and then nested one but I can't figure it out:

```sql
SELECT  acct,
        seq,
        chk,
        dense_rank() OVER (partition by acct, chk oRDER BY seq)  as counter1,
        row_number() OVER (partition by acct, chk oRDER BY seq)  as counter2
FROM    tableName
order by acct,seq
```

Comment: Thanks all three answers worked for me. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the output could be created using a single windowing function.  Something like this

```
select *, seq-max(case when chk>0 then 0 else seq end)
                over (partition by acct order by seq) as [counter]
from #TableName
order by acct, seq;
```

Output

```
acct    seq chk counter
123     1   1   1
123     2   1   2
123     3   1   3
123     4   0   0
123     5   1   1
123     6   1   2
124     1   0   0
124     2   1   1
124     3   1   2
124     4   0   0
124     5   1   1
124     6   1   2
```

Comment: found this to be the cleanest of the codes even though all worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a cumulative sum to define the groups and then `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when chk = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by acct, grp, chk order by seq)
             else 0
        end) as counter
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - chk) over (partition by acct order by seq) as grp
      from tablename t
     ) t
order by acct, seq
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4870ee68181bb1d305565bee811d11b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks sorry I probably didn't make it clear which I now edited but the counter column is the one I want to create.

Comment: @Lorbat . . . That was just a typo on my part -- I misread which column is which.

Answer (score 1):

The following produces your desired results with the logic in comments.

```
with cte as (
  select *
    -- Step 1 - detect changes in the chk value
    , case when lag(chk,1,0) over (order by acct, seq) <> chk and chk = 0 then 1 else 0 end lagged
  from #TableName
)
select acct, seq, chk
  -- Step 3 - get the row number using the chk partitioning
  , case when chk = 1 then row_number() over (partition by acct, chk, sumlagged order by seq) else 0 end [counter]
from (
  select *
    -- Step 2 - sum change in chk so they provide a distinct value for partitioning
    , sum(lagged) over (order by acct, seq) sumlagged
  from cte
) x
order by acct, seq;
```